# Oracle. Can't understand how FOR works with subquery SELECT INTO

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Found strange thing. Can't understand why Oracle allow this query and why `cnt` variable doesn't change after it's execution:

```
declare cnt number;
begin
 for r in (Select count(1) into cnt from  v$session) loop
   dbms_output.put_line(cnt);
 END LOOP; 
end;
```

`Select count(1) from v$session` returns not null value

Of course I've understand:

1. That `FOR` doesn't need in this situation. `Count` without `INTO` retuns only one row.
2. That I can use it without `INTO` and it will works.

Just curious how and why it works in query above.

It's strange why Oracle allow subquery with `SELECT INTO`, because in common situation Oracle returns compilation error ORA-06550

```
declare cnt number;
 begin
        select count(1) from  (Select count(1) into cnt from  v$session)
 end;
or
```

And if first query works - why it doesn't return cnt value correctly?

Comment: please have a look at my answer. You should name your columns in the for select statement. Handle `r` like a table row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very interesting, I'd say this is a bug except it's a benign one. The `INTO cnt` bit is valid PL/SQL but is ignored in this context, which can be proven with a simple test case:

```
declare cnt number;
begin
 for r in (select count(1) into cnt from dual) loop
   dbms_output.put_line('cnt=' || cnt);
   dbms_output.put_line('r=' || r."COUNT(1)");
 end loop;
end;
```

As you can see, the `INTO` clause is ignored, and as expected the `r` record is correctly populated. Output on my 11gR2 instance:

```
cnt=
r=1
```

Answer (score 4):

**Correct sql statement**

try this

```
declare cnt number;
begin
 for r in (Select count(1) as cnt from  v$session) loop
   dbms_output.put_line(r.cnt);
 END LOOP; 
end;
```

**Explanation**

*select_statement*

SQL SELECT statement (not PL/SQL SELECT INTO statement). For select_statement, PL/SQL declares, opens, fetches from, and closes an implicit cursor. However, because select_statement is not an independent statement, the implicit cursor is internal—you cannot reference it with the name SQL.

see http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/cursor_for_loop_statement.htm#LNPLS1155

the `cnt` variable is ignored, this can be proved by the following example, because no error is raised:

```
declare
  cnt       number;
  a_varchar varchar2(1);
begin
  for r in (Select 'AA' into a_varchar from v$session) loop
    dbms_output.put_line(a_varchar);
  end loop;
end;
```

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu I've tested it without problems.

Comment: My bad, I've made a mistake in my code. You're correct.

Comment: Yep, it works. +1 to answer. But this doesn't explain why it works incorrect with INTO

Comment: @ViktorBardakov That's right, this is unclear. I've upvoted your question for more attention

Comment: @sstan you are right, i have merged the second answer to the first.

Comment: Not sure about your statement *"the cnt variable is changend in an inner block, but the changement is lost by leaving the sql statement and entering the loop statement"* - what do you base this on?

Comment: @JeffreyKemp You are right, the variable is ignored but must be declared, this is quite strange. See my correction.

Comment: Agree all the values should be taken directly from r.